# Will renal blood flow decrease in response to dehydration?

Tags: physiology, blood-pressure, renal-physiology, osmoregulation, dehydration

If dehydrated, does the correction of ECF osmolarity happen slowly enough for ECF (and therefore plasma) volume to be temporarily depleted and therefore reduce renal blood flow?

If dehydration is taken to mean ECF hyperosmolarity, would fluid not just move out of cells to restore normal osmolarity, without affecting ECF volume or renal blood flow?

Comment: Please spell out any abbreviations that are not widely used. Specifically, what does ECF mean?

Comment: Apologies: extracellular fluid.